# Want to Insert Data in multiple tables according to different class objects in Android Application using Room Database Library transaction

Tags: java, android, transactions, android-room

I have a layout in my android application in which I have to fill various details of Student like Student Personal Details, Address Details and Course Details for admission.

I have 3 different Entity Class for each of above named as Person, Person Address and Course Details.
I have wrapped the object of these entity classes by using the data from Edit Text of Layout.

Now, my problem is that I have to Insert all these object's data into a single transaction by using Primary Key and Foreign Key Reference means the ID generated in Person Table have to use in Address and Course Details at the time of insertion in same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a Dao method that is annotated with @Query("SQL statement that interacts with multiple tables to perform your desired action :parameters")
void insertDetails(parameters)

check this link to see the syntax for passing parameters into a Dao method
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Thanx for the response. Plz share some sample code if you have because I am a new learner of Android